# Visual studio c++ static analysis plugin for feeding into sonar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, static-analysis, sonarqube

Is there any way to feed visual studio static analysis on c++ code base into sonar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the [VSSonarExtension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7fc312c3-f1ab-49f8-b286-dbf7fff37305)? Some hints on how to use it your can find [here](http://vssonarextension.blogspot.de/).

**Update:**
The other way around there may be a plugin by jmecosta called [VSSonarAddin](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/New-Visual-Studio-Addin-to-Interface-with-Sonar-td5007146.html). One of its features is

> "c++, runs local analysis with cppcheck and reports violations added
>   by local changes. "

You can find the project on [github](https://github.com/jmecosta/VSSonarAddin).

Comment: As I understand this extension integrates sonar analysis into visual studio, not the other way around. I need something that will export visual studio analysis into sonar.

Answer (score -2):

The Community C++ Plugin supports feeding compiler warnings as violations into SonarQube. You usually need to build your code with code analysis enabled and later you can use that data during SonarQube analysis. See [here](https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/wiki/Compilers) for more details!